# haml_tag not returning any string

Tags: haml, helper, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hi I've tried to copy my old haml_tags and it seems either they are not working for Rails 3.1rc4 or i'm doing somethign wrong. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
def bonus_value_of(stat)
  bonus = current_user.character.send("bonus_#{stat}".to_sym)
  capture_haml do
    haml_tag :span, :class => "positive" do
      "+#{bonus}"
    end
  end
end
```

thats my code which i call with

```
= bonus_value_of(stat)
```

and all i get is a blank span with positive class but no content(not even the plus)

is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my version.

1.Your helper should be in controller's helper, not in `module Haml::Helper` like it was described in some article.

2.Change your helper to this:

```
def bonus_value_of(stat)
  bonus = current_user.character.send("bonus_#{stat}".to_sym)
  haml_tag :span, :class => "positive" do
    haml_concat "+#{bonus}"
  end
end
```

And then use it in your view like this:

```
- bonus_value_of(stat)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this. I needed to pass my span text as the second value to `haml_tag`.

```
def bonus_value_of(stat)
  bonus = current_user.character.send("bonus_#{stat}".to_sym)
  capture_haml do
    haml_tag :span, "+#{bonus}", :class => "positive"
  end
end
```